# Prevent jsTree from drag and drop when dnd is not activated

Tags: jstree

I'm using jsTree and do NOT want to be able to drag'n'drop elements of the tree. So I also didn't load the `dnd` plugin.

But I'm still able to drag elements...

This effect can also easily be seen on the examples on the jsTree homepage (main page, the two trees on the upper right - both trees also aren't including the dnd plugin).

=> How can I get the behaviour that I want?

(If that's relevant: I'm using version 3.0.8 and the minimized version out of the `dist` directory. This is happening in Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: Well, you could easily check the jsTree homepage. But I've also just created http://jsfiddle.net/cvanLcq3/ for it to play around...